# overflow property not cutting off jQuery carousel content

Tags: css, carousel

Okay, I know. Trust me, I know. This seems like an easy fix. But, the solutions has been eluding me for a while now.

I'm using a jQuery [carousel](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/) plugin. I can't seem to get the carousel to cut off at the end of the div that it's nested in.

```
<div style='overflow:hidden;margin:0 auto;'>
     <div class='carousel'>
<?php
     for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
     {
          echo "<div>
                    ".$content[$i]."
               </div>";
     }
 ?>
     </div>
</div>
```

You can find a working example [here](http://sportannica.com/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are giving `overflow:hidden` to wrong parent element. Try giving `overflow:hidden` to `li` element and also give  `position:relative` to it. Problem will be solved. :)

```
li{
  /* other css properties */
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: That does actually work. But, it just creates some more problems... shrug

Comment: @Lance you are welcome. Not sure why but your parent div which has `overflow:hidden` doesn't have any width and height. If you give `width`, `height` and `position:relative` to your parent div and also remove `left:500px` (carousel) from the child div, then it will work properly too.